# lmfit Stepped functions and Step size

Tags: python, lmfit

I want to fit a `2D` shape in an image. In the past, I have successfully done this using `lmfit` in Python and wrapping the `2D` function/data to `1D`. On that occasion, the `2D` model was a smooth function (a ring with a gaussian profile). Now I am trying to do the same but with a "non-smooth function" and it is not working as expected.

This is what I am trying to do (guessed and fitted are the same):

[image]

I have shifted the guessed parameters in purpose to easily see if it moves as expected, and nothing happens.

I have noticed that if instead of a swiss flag I use a `2D` gaussian, which is a smooth function, this works fine (see MWE below):

[image]

So I guess the problem is related to the fact that the Swiss flag function is not smooth. I have tried to make it smooth by adding a gaussian filter (blur) but it still did not work, even though the swiss flag plot became very blurred.

After some time I came to the thought that maybe the step size that is using `lmfit` (o whoever is in the background) is too small to produce any change in the swiss flag. I would like to try to increase the step size to 1, but I don't know exactly how to do that.

This is my MWE (sorry, it is still quite long):

```
import numpy as np
import myplotlib as mpl # https://github.com/SengerM/myplotlib
import lmfit

def draw_swiss_flag(fig, center, side, **kwargs):
    fig.plot(
        np.array(2*[side] + 2*[side/2] + 2*[-side/2] + 2*[-side] + 2*[-side/2] + 2*[side/2] + 2*[side]) + center[0],
        np.array([0] + 2*[side/2] + 2*[side] + 2*[side/2] + 2*[-side/2] + 2*[-side] + 2*[-side/2] + [0]) + center[1],
        **kwargs,
    )

def swiss_flag(x, y, center: tuple, side: float):
    # x, y numpy arrays.
    if x.shape != y.shape:
        raise ValueError(f'<x> and <y> must have the same shape!')
    flag = np.zeros(x.shape)
    flag[(center[0]-side/2<x)&(x<center[0]+side/2)&(center[1]-side<y)&(y<center[1]+side)] = 1
    flag[(center[1]-side/2<y)&(y<center[1]+side/2)&(center[0]-side<x)&(x<center[0]+side)] = 1
    return flag

def gaussian_2d(x, y, center, side):
    return np.exp(-(x-center[0])**2/side**2-(y-center[1])**2/side**2)

def wrapper_for_lmfit(x, x_pixels, y_pixels, function_2D_to_wrap, *params):
    pixel_number = x # This is the pixel number in the data array
    # x_pixels and y_pixels are the number of pixels that the image has. This is needed to make the mapping.
    if (pixel_number > x_pixels*y_pixels - 1).any():
        raise ValueError('pixel_number (x) > x_pixels*y_pixels - 1')
    x = np.array([int(p%x_pixels) for p in pixel_number])
    y = np.array([int(p/x_pixels) for p in pixel_number])
    return function_2D_to_wrap(x, y, *params)

data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt') # Read data
data -= data.min().min()
data = data/data.max().max()

guessed_center = (data.sum(axis=0).argmax()+11, data.sum(axis=1).argmax()+11) # I am adding 11 in purpose.
guessed_side = 19

model = lmfit.Model(lambda x, xc, yc, side: wrapper_for_lmfit(x, data.shape[1], data.shape[0], swiss_flag, (xc,yc), side))
params = model.make_params()
params['xc'].set(value = guessed_center[0], min = 0, max = data.shape[1])
params['yc'].set(value = guessed_center[1], min = 0, max = data.shape[0])
params['side'].set(value = guessed_side, min = 0)
fit_results = model.fit(data.ravel(), params, x = [i for i in range(len(data.ravel()))])

mpl.manager.set_plotting_package('matplotlib')
fit_plot = mpl.manager.new(
    title = 'Data vs fit',
    aspect = 'equal',
)
fit_plot.colormap(data)
draw_swiss_flag(fit_plot, guessed_center, guessed_side, label = 'Guessed')
draw_swiss_flag(fit_plot, (fit_results.params['xc'],fit_results.params['yc']), fit_results.params['side'], label = 'Fitted')

swiss_flag_plot = mpl.manager.new(
    title = 'Swiss flag plot',
    aspect = 'equal',
)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.array([i for i in range(data.shape[1])]), np.array([i for i in range(data.shape[0])]))
swiss_flag_plot.colormap(
    z = swiss_flag(xx, yy, center = (fit_results.params['xc'],fit_results.params['yc']), side = fit_results.params['side']),
)

mpl.manager.show()
```

and [this](https://cernbox.cern.ch/index.php/s/vhw4yvrH5OXLaXg) is the content of `data.txt`.

Comment: The link to data.txt is not working. "The file you requested has been deleted"

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, try with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code is all fine. The issue is, as you already guessed, that the algorithm used by lmfit is not dealing well with non-smooth data.

By default lmfit uses a leas squares method. Let's change it to method `'differential_evolution'` instead.

```py
params['side'].set(value=guessed_side, min=0, max=len(data))
fit_results = model.fit(data.ravel(), params,
                        x=[i for i in range(len(data.ravel()))],
                        method='differential_evolution'
                        )
```

Note that I needed to add some finite value for the max value to prevent a "differential_evolution requires finite bound for all varying parameters" message.

After switching to the evolutionary algorithm, the fit now looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am still curious, do you know if in this case the problem is that ```swiss_flag``` function is not smooth or the fact that the data is taken in integer points? Or maybe the combination of both at the same time?

Comment: I assume the the flatness of the cross function is the problem here. This leads to vanishing derivatives in many points. This is something the Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm (which I assume is used by the underlying libraries here) cannot handle well.

Comment: So in fact, the problem is probably not that the target function is not smooth enough but actually too smooth in that it has many regions with a disappearing gradient.

Answer (score 0):

All the fitting algorithms in `lmfit` (and `scipy.optimize` for that matter), and including the "global optimizers" really work on continuous variables (double precision).   When trying to find the optimal parameter values, most of the algorithms will make a very small step (at the ~1.e-7 level) in the value to determine the derivative which will then be used to make the next guess of the optimal values.

The problem you're seeing is that your model function uses the parameter value as discrete values - as the index of an array using `int()`.   If a small change is made to the parameter value, no change in the result will be detected - the algorithm will decide that the fit result does not depend on small changes to that value.

The so-called "global solvers" like differential evolution, basin-hopping, shgo, take the view that the derivative approach can lead to "false minima" and so will "spray parameter space" with lots of candidate values and then use different strategies to refine the best of those results to find the optimal values.  Generally speaking, these are much slower to run (OTOH runtime is cheap!) and very good for problems where there may be multiple "minima" and you really want to find the best of these, or where getting a decent guess of starting values is very hard.

For your problem, it is pretty clear that you can guess starting values (the center pixels must be on the image, say, so maybe guess "the middle"), and it seems likely from the image that there are not a lot of false minima that might be found.  That means that the expense of a global solver might not be needed.

Another approach would be to allow your shaped object to be centered at any continuous center in the image, and not only at integer pixels.  Of course, you do have to map that to the discrete image, but it doesn't need to fully on/off.  Using a sigmoidal functions like `scipy.special.erf()` and `erfc()` will allow you to still have a transition from "on" to "off", but with a small but finite width, bleeding into adjacent pixels.   And that would be enough to allow a fit to find a continuous (and so, sub-pixel!) value for the center position.  In 1-d, that might look like::

```
from scipy.special import erf
def smoothed_window(x, edge1, edge2, width):
    return (erf((x-edge1)/width) + erf((edge2-x)/width))/2.0
```

For integer x values, a `width` of 0.5 (that is, half a pixel) will almost certainly allow a fit to find sub-integer values for `edge1` and `edge2`. (Aside: either force the `width` parameter to be fixed or force it to be positive, eithr in the code or at the Parameter level).

I have not tried to extend that to your more complicated "swiss flag" function, but it should be possible and also work for fitting center values.